# How to sort values via XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

These is my XML.

```
<root>

<element>
<title>Title .. </title>
<val>2</val>
<date>21/01/2011</date>
</element>

<element>
<title>Title .. </title>
<val>1</val>
<date>21/01/2011</date>
</element>

<element>
<title>Title .. </title>
<val>2</val>
<date>22/01/2011</date>
</element>

</root>
```

The logic is this:
Element nodes should be ranked according to node val and date. First Order must be based on val and within this sequence of nodes with val value. They should be listed by date.

Does anyone know how to get a sorted list of XML nodes via XPath?

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that XPath itself doesn't support sorting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480673/sort-with-xpath-not-xsl Not sure whether this is true for the newest versions of XPath.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `xsl:sort` to sort matching nodes. This will allow you to sort by your `val` element. However, XPath 1.0 does not have a date data-type. A reasonable solution to this problemm is to split your date into its year, month and day components and sort by each individually. The following should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="val" data-type="number" order="descending"/>

        <!-- year sort -->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(date,7,4)" data-type="number" />
        <!-- month sort -->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(date,4,2)" data-type="number" />
        <!-- day sort -->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(date,1,2)" data-type="number" />        
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks - your deleted answer looked good to me too. The translate() function was a bit cunning ;-)

Comment: It didn't work due that numbers were as big as day number :) I started to write substring, but you already did.

Comment: If you are in charge of the XML design (or even if you aren't...) it's always better to hold dates in ISO format YYYY-MM-DD rather than as dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy. It avoids ambiguity for the human reader, and it's easier for software to process.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that XPath 3.1 offers sorting:

Signatures

```
fn:sort($input as item()*) as item()*
fn:sort($input as item()*,  
    $collation as xs:string?) as item()*
fn:sort($input as item()*,  
    $collation as xs:string?,  
    $key as function(item()) as xs:anyAtomicType*) as item()*
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-sort