# Sort with XPath - Not XSL

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Is there any way in XPath DOM Programming with using `System.Xml` to run `selectNodes` (XPATH) with a sort parameter?

For example, with the following XML and program writes values in the same order as the document (descending).  Is there a way using XPath to get the values in ascending order?

NOTE.  Of course, you could pre-sort in XSL, however I need to update the values as I'm looping through them.  Since XSL gives me a sorted **copy** of the elements, *not the actual elements themselves*, I can't use XSL.

Here's some XML, a program out output

```
public static void Main() {

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load( "t.xml" );

        // SelectNodes gets in document order, but I want in 
            // ascending order based on @value
        foreach( XmlNode ndNode in xml.SelectNodes( "/xml/ele" ) ) {
            Console.WriteLine( ndNode.Attributes["value"].Value );
        }
    }
```

Here's the XML

```
<xml>
<ele value='3' test='Third'/>
<ele value='2' test='Second'/>
<ele value='1' test='First'/>
</xml>
```

Finally the output in document (descending) order.  I'd like an XPath that returns the nodes in ascending order.

```
3
2
1
```

PS, I'm using `System.Xml` in Visual Studio 2008 .NET 3.5

Comment: From your sample, I can't see why XSL wouldn't work for you.  What exactly is it about the original elements that means you must modify them?

Comment: XPath 2.0 has a `reverse` function.

Comment: Hi Paul, to clarify, I need to update the elements in the loop.  As I iterate each element contains an effective and expiration date.  I need the elements sorted by effective date, and set the expiration date to be the next effective date.  Sure, I guess it could be done in XSL by outputing a copy of the document, but I'm looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: Does changing the node have any effect anywhere else?  e.g. some other object holds a pointer to the nodes, and changing the values changes the behaviour of some other object.  If not, then you don't need to modify the original elements.  If you are loading, altering and saving a document, then that saved document is no more the original than the output of an XSL transformation would be.

Comment: You're right Paul, it could be done in XSL.  I've done it that way in the past.  I'm just looking for another way.

Comment: It seems that XPath 3.1 offers sorting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48361579/502187

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XPath doesn't supprort ordering, however you may look at `AddSort` method.

Comment: Wojteq, thanks yet another way to solve this.  Seems a little cleaner than LINQ.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no way to do sorting in XPath alone.

But you can easily use LINQ to sort your collection of nodes by whatever values you want.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument ();
xml.LoadXml("<xml> <ele value='3' test='Third'/> <ele value='2' test='Second'/> <ele value='1' test='First'/> </xml>");
var nodes = xml.SelectNodes( "/xml/ele" ).Cast<XmlNode>().OrderBy(ndNode => ndNode.Attributes["value"].Value);
```

Comment: Interesting, but isn't LINQ just for converting SQL datasets into XML?  My XML isn't in a database.

Comment: No. You talking about LINQ-to-SQL that is subset of LINQ functionlaity. I've added sample how to get collection of nodes you need if you want to stick with XmlDocument. You may also want to consider LINQ-to-XML (XDocument,...).

Comment: Thanks Alexi, LINQ looks like a winner.  I appreciate you bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Wrong. XPath 2.0 **can** sort (proof: http://www.ximeco.org/Xime/XPathCanSortHlousek.pdf). With XPath 3.0 it becomes efficient and easy.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin Sure. Note that question was "with using System.Xml" which means OP is limited to XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling upon this question later, XPath 3.1 has a sort function.