# When XPath uses the preceding-sibling axis ,I want to return the nodes in a reverse order ? How ?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

Given the Following XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE stock SYSTEM "new.dtd">
<stock>
    <book num="myBook1">
        <title>Lindsy Boxer</title>
        <author>James Patterson</author>
        <publisher>LittleBig</publisher>
        <price>18.21</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Alex Cross Is Back - Chapter A</title>
            <paragraph>
                This is the <emph>first</emph> paragraph.
                <image file="alexCrossImage.gif"/>
                afetr image...
            </paragraph>
            <paragraph>
                This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph.
                <image file="alexCrossImageAnother.gif"/>
                afetr image...
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B</title>
            <section>
                <title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B - section 1</title>
                <paragraph>
                    This is the <emph>first</emph>paragraph for chapter TWO section ONE.
                    <image file="Chapter_B_firstParagraphImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
                </paragraph>
                <paragraph>
                    This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph for chapter TWO section ONE.
                    <image file="Chapter_B_secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
                </paragraph>
            </section>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Chapter C</title>
            <paragraph>
                This chapter has no images and only one paragraph
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <book num="myBook2">
        <title>Jack Reacher Series</title>
        <author>Lee Child</author>
        <author>Jonny White</author>
        <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
        <price>5.99</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Jack Reacher - Chapter ONE</title>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Jack Reacher - Chapter TWO</title>
            <paragraph>
                This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph of SECOND book chapter TWO.
                <image file="Jack_Reacher_Picture_Top_Sniper_US_Army.gif"/>
                afetr image...
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <book num="myBook3">
        <title>Alex Cross - Double Cross</title>
        <author>James Patterson</author>
        <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
        <price>17.30</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Alex Cross - Double Cross - Chapter A</title>
        </chapter>
    </book>
</stock>
```

When I enter the following query :

```
Object myQuery= xpath.evaluate("stock/book/chapter[3]/preceding-sibling::chapter//title",doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I get the output as :

```
<title>Alex Cross Is Back - Chapter A</title>
<title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B</title>
<title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B - section 1</title>
```

**But what I want is when my XPath uses the preceding-sibling axis ,I want to return the nodes in 
a reverse order  , i.e. :**

```
         *  <title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B</title>
         *  <title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B - section 1</title>
         *  <title>Alex Cross Is Back - Chapter A</title>
```

So basically ,as you can see ,Java returns the nodes in a mixed order , by the order of the nodes in the XML file , but what I need is , when XPath uses the preceding-sibling axis ,then return the nodes in a reverse order .

This is not the one and only command where this kind of "behavior" is happening (returning mixed nodes) .

My objective is to fix this , I've tried to change `XPath's` `evalute` , but it's still doesn't work .

Can anyone give some directions / hints how to do this ?

P.S

Using this piece of code :

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("new.xml");
        //create an XPath factory
        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        //create an XPath Object
        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
        //***********************************************************//
        Object myQuery= xpath.evaluate("stock/book/chapter[3]/preceding-sibling::chapter//title",doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("The Results are:");
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) myQuery;
        //print the output
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("i: " + i);
            System.out.println("*******");
            System.out.println(nodeToString(nodes.item(i)));
            System.out.println("*******");
        }
```

I got the above result (the mixed nodes)

Comment: Why do you expect to get the nodes in that order?

Comment: Also, this q is eerily similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547114

Comment: The nodes selected as result of evaluating an XPath expression are always returned in *document order* --whay do you expect XPath to know about someon's (yours) preferred order? There are no facilities in XPath 1.0 for specifying a different order. In XPath 2.0 one can construct a sequence that could be in any desired order.

Comment: It isn't clear from your question what your desired order is -- it would be good to edit and provide an explanation. People cannot guess what you consider a "good" order -- nor can XPath.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Question edited in the original post . What I want is to when XPath uses the preceding-sibling axis ,then return the nodes in a reverse order .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the selected nodes returned in an order that isn't their document order.

**This isn't possible with today's XPath 1.0 engines** -- all of them are returning the selected nodes in document order. And XPath 1.0 doesn't have means for any special order to be specified.

Therefore, if you are using XPath 1.0 (which seems to be the case), you will have to live with that -- for example index the results not with increasing index but with a decreasing one.

**In XPath 2.0 there are *sequences* and you can write an XPath expression and specify each of the items in a sequence**.

Or (again in XPath 2.0) you can just have:

```
reverse(yourExpression)
```

and this will produce the reverse sequence of items  -- of the sequence of items produced by `yourExpression`.

Comment: The problem is that I need to fix it , but I don't know how to accomplish that under XPath 1.0 , and not (!!) XPath 2.0 . Can you please kindly explain how can I do that ? I have no problem to rewrite "evaluate" , or any other function , however this subject (XPath) is very new to me . Much appreciated .

Comment: @ron: As I started in this answer, this *cannot* be done with XPath 1.0 only -- you will have to process the returned node-list in reverse order -- that is not from `0` to `count(yourExpr) -1` with incrementing index, but from `count(yourExpr) -1` to `0` with decrementing index.

Comment: But please notice, that this "problem" does not happen always with every query that I put into XPath evaluation , but only when I deal with preceding-sibling axis , so I cannot perform a "reverse" on every result that XPath return , since some of them would be wrong (those results that are not connected to preceding-sibling axis)

Comment: @ron: Where did I say that you should process in reverse order *every* XPath expression? No, my response is to your particular problem only.

Comment: That's the problem I'm trying to solve , the general case , and not regarding the query I wrote above (meaning "stock/book/chapter[3]/preceding-sibling::chapter//title") . I want to support all queries with the requested "fix" that I mentioned , where some queries would need the "fix" (since they  deal with preceding-sibling axis) and some won't need it (since they don't  deal with preceding-sibling axis) .

Comment: @ron: Then you have wrong understanding of XPath -- there never will be a possiblity of treating the results of all XPath expressions in the same way -- this is rather meaningless. You need to read more on "reverse axes" in XPath and see that the semantics of the `position()` function is different at the time of evaluating expressions containing reverse axes. In XPath 2.0 such general treatment becomes even more impossible -- there are so many possible types of the result of evaluation...

Comment: Since I need to "solve" a "problem" of XPath 1.0 ,I can't use XPath 2.0 to solve it  :) any other suggestions maybe ? I've looked at countless tutorials for the last 14 hours however found nothing concrete that might help solve this . I'd appreciate any help , thanks .

Comment: @ron: You have my strongest assurance that I haven't seen or heard of any XPath 1.0 implementation that returns selected nodes in other than document order. Maybe you have enough free time to spend on looking for inexisting implementations, but my advice is to spend this time on something more productive :)

Comment: Then my only option is to find all the problematic inputs and take care of them , am I right ?

Comment: @ron: I don't think the input (XML) needs to be changed -- and often this isn't permitted. Even when this is possible, another application may need to select some nodes of the modified document using reverse axis... One simply should process any node-list that is the XPath engine representation of the selected nodes by an XPath expression knowing that the selected nodes are always ordered in this node-list in their ascending document order.

Answer (score 1):

In fact this is not 'mixed' order. This is just a result of [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) performed by XPath. And you need, as I can see, a [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). The DFS result will be just like a plain search result - what appears first in the document, that will appear earlier in search result.

You could try to implement it yourself by using [StAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html) - a stream reader. That is not DFS, but plain XML reader which could give you a desired result.

Comment: So basically Alex ,you suggest that I write "Stax" mechanism ? what is this exactly and what's is its connection to Xpath ?

Comment: it is not connected to XPath. it is streaming XML-parser. If you will use it - you should change your search strategy to searching for nodes with specific values inside.

Comment: I need to work with XPath . If I could use any other parser then I would have.One thing I do think, that if this "problem" was not solvable using Xpath 1.0 , I wouldn't have been given this. I've tried to search for hints and/or examples/solutions for the last day ,but found nothing .Do you have any idea or suggestion ? thanks :)

Comment: Hi, did you ever find out how to do this? I have to do the same now and can't find any way to do it.