# Are the messages from an xpath-splitter ordered?

Tags: java, xpath, spring-integration, saxon

Can I depend on the order of the messages output from an `int-xml:xpath-splitter`?

I am using:

- Java 1.6
- spring-integration-xml-3.0.0.RELEASE
- spring-xml-2.1.1.RELEASE
- Saxon-HE-9.4.0-9

Example:

Given the following XML Document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
    <test>test</test>
    <test>test2</test>
</tests>
```

And the following `int-xml:xpath-splitter`:

```xml
<int-xml:xpath-splitter id="messageSplitter" 
input-channel="inbound"
    output-channel="routing"
    create-documents="false">

    <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="/*/*"/>
</int-xml:xpath-splitter>

<int:channel id="routing">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
```

Will the `routing` channel always receive `<test>test</test>` before `<test>test2</test>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer to this question is it depends on which JAXP provider you are using.

If you have configured an XPath engine that supports XPath 2.0; then yes, messages will be in document-order.

If you use the default or an XPath 1.0 engine; then no, order cannot be guaranteed<sup>1</sup>.

---

### Does XPath support ordering?

XPath 1.0 does not<sup>1</sup>, XPath 2.0 does.

According to the [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction) specification, XPath 1.0 expressions return `node-set` types and `node-set` types are unordered:

> The primary syntactic construct in XPath is the expression. An expression matches the production Expr. An expression is evaluated to yield an object, which has one of the following four basic types:
>
> - node-set (an unordered collection of nodes without duplicates)
> - boolean (true or false)
> - number (a floating-point number)
> - string (a sequence of UCS characters)

On the other hand, the XPath 2.0 specification introduces the idea of [document order](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-document-order):

> Document order is a total ordering, although the relative order of some nodes is implementation-dependent. [Definition: Informally, document order is the order in which nodes appear in the XML serialization of a document.] [Definition: Document order is stable, which means that the relative order of two nodes will not change during the processing of a given expression, even if this order is implementation-dependent.]

The specification also states that evaluation of [Path Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-path-expressions) returns a sequence of nodes in document order:

> The sequences resulting from all the evaluations of E2 are combined as follows:
>
> If every evaluation of E2 returns a (possibly empty) sequence of nodes, these sequences are combined, and duplicate nodes are eliminated based on node identity. The resulting node sequence is returned in document order.
>   If every evaluation of E2 returns a (possibly empty) sequence of atomic values, these sequences are concatenated, in order, and returned.
>   If the multiple evaluations of E2 return at least one node and at least one atomic value, a type error is raised [err:XPTY0018].

### Does Spring Integration/Spring XML use XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0?

Spring uses [javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(String uri)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html#newInstance(java.lang.String)) to create an XPathFactory that is used to create `XPath` objects. The JavaDoc explains in detail how `XPathFactory.newInstance(uri)` behaves, but suffice it to say that it searches for an appropriate factory within your project.

If your project does not specify differently, Spring will use a JAXP 1.3 implementation to create XPath Expressions.

As of Java 1.6, JAXP 1.3 [only supports XPath 1.0](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxp/).

### What if I have an XPathFactory that supports XPath 2.0?

Refer to the documentation for the XPathFactory you are using.

In my case, I have Saxon-HE-9.4.0-9 setup for my project. Saxon [implements the JAXP 1.3 API and Supports XPath 2.0](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/xpath-api/jaxp-xpath/).

The Saxon documentation for [how XPath's are evaluated](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/xpath/XPathExpressionImpl.html#evaluate%28java.lang.Object,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29) does not explicitly state that `NODESET` expressions will be returned in document-order. However, it does state that the return object is a Java List object.

Based on the fact that XPath 2.0 expressions return nodes in document-order, Saxon supports XPath 2.0, and Saxon returns a Java List object (which is ordered), I think that Saxon will return nodes in document-order.

### So my factory returns nodes from my XPath expression in document-order; are the messages from `xpath-splitter` also in document-order?

Yes they will; based on **my analysis** of the code in `org.springframework.integration.xml.splitter.XPathMessageSplitter.splitMessage(Message<?>)`.

Both `splitDocument(document)` and `splitNode(Node node)` retain the order of the List returned from the evaluation of the XPath Expression.

---

<sub>1. As noted by Michael Kay in his comment and [answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548136/953327), although the XPath *specification* does not guarantee order, in practice implementations of XPath 1.0 generally also support [XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116) and will return nodes in document-order because XSLT requires it.</sub>

Comment: An amazingly detailed and largely correct answer. While it is true that the XPath 1.0 spec talks of xpath expressions returning node-sets (therefore, order undefined), and few APIs add anything about node order, in practice, most XPath 1.0 engines are built to support the needs of XSLT 1.0, which always processes node-sets in document order, and as a result, I've never come across an XPath engine whose node-sets aren't routinely delivered in document order.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelKay, I have made a note of this in my answer.